# Tensor product with any Noetherian integral domain is Noetherian

Tags: commutative-algebra, noetherian, integral-domain

Let $k$ be a field. Algebras are assumed to be commutative, associative, unital. If for a $k$-algebra the $k$-tensor product with any Noetherian integral domain over $k$ is Noetherian, is the $k$-tensor product with any Noetherian $k$-algebra Noetherian?

Comment: Such a ring needs to be Noetherian as $k$ is a domain. Then you can see that the tensor product in your question is Noetherian.

Comment: @Youngsu I don't think I understand you. The tensor product of two Noetherian algebras is not necessarily Noetherian (e.g. $\overline{\mathbb{Q}}\otimes_{\mathbb{Q}}\overline{\mathbb{Q}}$).

Comment: I am sorry about my comment above. I misunderstood your question. As the ring in your question need not be a finite type over $k$ or a quotient of a Noetherian domain, my argument does not work.